# Check if a user is also a fan using JS

Tags: facebook

I am beginner at FB app development, and I am trying to figure it out how to check if a user currently browsing my page is also a fan.

I have a appID, pageID, and would like to use JS, but dont really know where am I mistaking

Here is the code

```
<%@ Page Language="c#" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="test" Codebehind="test.aspx.cs" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>


    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

FB.init({ 
    appId:'validappID', 
    cookie:false, 
    status:true, 
    xfbml:true
});

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if(response.session) {
            alert('connected to Application');
        } else {
            // no user session available, someone you dont know
            if(response.status == "notConnected") {
                // But user is logged into facebook
                alert("Not connected to Application, but is logged in to Facebook");
            } else {
                // User is not logged into facebook
                  alert('Not logged in to facebook');
            }
        }
    });

    </script>


    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing the channelUrl in the FB.init() call.  Also I'd change the code to load the SDK Async as described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/, once you do those things, let me know if you're still having problems.